# Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0} on websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

We are migrating our Web application from WAS5.1 (Java 1.4) to WAS8.5(Java 7) using Eclipse Oxygen and WAS Migration Toolkit plug in.

We are able to build and publish application successfully on WAS8.5 local server but while accessing home page of application, we are getting below error. We don't have any special setting at container level for WAS5.1 but not sure what is missing here.

> Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}.

Comment: According to the help from IBM (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/181284/why-am-i-getting-error-404-srve0190e-file-not-foun.html) it might be your server.xml

Comment: Application is working with same configuration files on WAS 6 but giving error on WAS 8.5.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs to see if there are any errors starting the application?

Comment: Nope I am not getting any errors while server start-up, researched on this issue most of the answers were pointing to context root & custom properties. Context root is correct for application & I did tried adding custom properties, however none of them was working.

Comment: Do you have any EJBs in your application? If so, did you install EJBDeploy with WAS 8.5 and did it run when the app deployed?

Comment: Is it WebSphere Liberty Profile, or Full Profile? Can you provide more details about your application configuration, like `application.xml` and `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to run an EAR on the server using Eclipse. I couldn't find an answer so **I deleted the EAR and the project from my computer and re-cloned the project and made a new EAR**. Somehow everything worked fine after doing that.. not going to question it. The old "unplug and plug back in".

Answer (score 0):

Please check the web.xml file. I faced same issue and found that web.xml was got overritten with some default values.Not sure how it happened.but changing it to old values was working fine.

Check the jsp pages and if any errors for jsp in web.xml also can cause issues